# send key strokes to a window in vb.net while it is still minimized

Tags: vb.net, sendkeys

I used to know vb6 and I need to make a quick application. I hope someone can help me with how to send keys to a minimized window in vb.net

thanks

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to accomplish? This sounds like a strange approach to a problem. Also, although there are some similarities, don't expect to be able to simply pick up VB.Net and decent code with it. It's a different (and much improved) animal to the ol' VB6... Give us some info on what you're trying to do and I'm sure we'll be able to make some constructive suggestions...

Comment: I want to control my media player using its shortcut keys so I was hoping there was a way to send shortcut keys to an application without maximizing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you can send keys with the `SendMessage` API function, but I'm not sure if it would be affected in any way by the window being minimized, I don't think so but I haven't tried.
To use a Windows API function from VB.Net you need to use PInvoke to call it, you can find information about how to do that on this [page](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.sendmessage).

The MSDN page for [SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950%28VS.85%29.aspx) might also be useful for information about how it works.

Btw, you probably want to use the `WM_CHAR` message which is `0x0102`.

Answer (score 0):

Use SendKeys

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx

```
SendKeys.SendWait()
```